# Issue parsing RSS feed in Exacttarget ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've got an email that uses the following to parse an RSS feed and print the last 5 blog posts. Now they want to print all blog posts from the past week. Any help?

```
    %%[Var @xml, @titles, @title, @descs,@pubdas,@pubda, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParsej") /* This line specifies the content area from which the RSS content will be pulled for the email message. */
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @pubdas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)

If RowCount(@titles) > 5 THEN
SET @rows = 5
ELSE
SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@cnt), "Value")
Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") ]%%

<div style="border-bottom: 1px  solid #CBCAD2; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:3px;">
<a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%%">%%=v(@title)=%%</a><span style=" font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; font-weight: normal;">     |      %%=Format(@pubda, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%</span><br/>
%%=v(@desc)=%%
</div>

%%[ 
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: We're going to have to know something about how you're getting the date for the blog posts.

Comment: It's coming from the RSS feed. Here is from the xml: <pubDate>Tue, 03 Jun 2014 14:00:00 GMT</pubDate>

Comment: This question is totally on topic, this is related to the ExactTarget programming language AMPscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to do is drop

```
If RowCount(@titles) > 5 THEN
  SET @rows = 5
ELSE
  SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF
```

Just use SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)

Then you need to add an IF to check the date right after

```
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
```

BUT, you will need to pull out

```
Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@cnt), "Value")
```

from the current code block so you can check the date.

You can check the date by using DateDiff.  It would look like

```
IF DateDiff(NOW(),@pubda, "D") <= 7
```

You then would end the IF block right before the NEXT keyword.

Hope this helps.