# Unable to generate preview An error occurred when attempting to parse HtmlEmailBody content for HTML content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to generate a customized RSS email that filters out to only show the past week's blog content as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38591/issue-parsing-rss-feed-in-exacttarget-ampscript). I get the following error every I try to generate a preview of the email:

```
Unable to generate preview
An error occurred when attempting to parse HtmlEmailBody content for HTML content.
MemberID: ...
JobID: 0
ListID: ...
Content Begins With:
LEVEL ONE



%%[VAR @xml, @ti
An error occurred when attempting to parse HtmlEmailBody content for HTML content.
MemberID: ...
JobID: 0
ListID: ...
Content Begins With: 
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
IF DateDiff(NOW(),@pubda, "D") 
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt
```

Here's my AMPscript:

```
<h1 style="font: bold normal 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">LEVEL ONE</h1>

%%[VAR @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @pubdas, @pubda, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParse-level-one")
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @pubdas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)

SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@cnt), "Value")

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
IF DateDiff(NOW(),@pubda, "D") <= 7
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") ]%%

<div style="border-bottom: 1px  solid #CBCAD2; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:3px;">
<a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%%">%%=v(@title)=%%</a><span style=" font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; font-weight: normal;">     |      %%=Format(@pubda, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%</span><br/>
%%=v(@desc)=%%
</div>

%%[ 
ENDIF
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5" Border=0><tr><td><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by: <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></font></td></tr></table>
<a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `THEN` on this line: `IF DateDiff(NOW(),@pubda, "D") <= 7`.

```
<h1 style="font: bold normal 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">LEVEL ONE</h1>
%%[
VAR @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @pubdas, @pubda, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParse-level-one")
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @pubdas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)

SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@cnt), "Value")

IF @rows >= 1 THEN

    for @cnt = 1 to @rows do

        IF DateDiff(NOW(),@pubda, "D") <= 7 THEN

        Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
        Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
        Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") 
]%%
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px  solid #CBCAD2; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:3px;">
            <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)=%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%%">%%=v(@title)=%%</a><span style=" font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; font-weight: normal;"> | %%=Format(@pubda, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%</span><br/>%%=v(@desc)=%%
        </div>
%%[ 
        ENDIF
    NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5" Border=0><tr><td><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by: <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></font></td></tr></table>
<a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
```

Both [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) have AMPScript syntax highlighting plugins.  It's helpful for catching things like this.  I'd also recommend using the Validate toolbar button in ET/SFMC.  It'll give you more details on AMPScript errors.

Comment: Wow, duh. Thanks so much. I had no idea about the plugin for Notepad++ - that's enormously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a variable, don't you need to add a comma at the end?

```
<h1 style="font: bold normal 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">LEVEL ONE</h1>

%%[VAR @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @pubdas, @pubda, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParse-level-one"),
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1),
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1),
Set @pubdas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1),
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1),

SET @rows = RowCount(@titles),
Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@cnt), "Value")

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
IF DateDiff(NOW(),@pubda, "D") <= 7
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value"),
Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value"),
Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") ]%%

<div style="border-bottom: 1px  solid #CBCAD2; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:3px;">
<a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%%">%%=v(@title)=%%</a><span style=" font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; font-weight: normal;">     |      %%=Format(@pubda, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%</span><br/>
%%=v(@desc)=%%
</div>

%%[ 
ENDIF
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5" Border=0><tr><td><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by: <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></font></td></tr></table>
<a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
```

Comment: The commas are not valid syntax.